# specific leaflet layer style to change dynamically based on django tags

Tags: django, leaflet, django-leaflet

Potion of my html code do do style

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
         function our_Layers (map, options){
            var datasets = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'owner' %}",{

                style: function colors(feature){                    
                    switch(feature.properties.lr){                        
                        case "{{LR}}":
                            return{
                                color: 'red'
                            };
                        break
                    }
                },

                onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
                    //layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.lr.toString());
                    layer.bindPopup('<strong>LR No.: </strong>'+ feature.properties.lr.toString()
                   );
                }
            });
            datasets.addTo(map); 

         }
    </script>

    {% leaflet_map "parcels" callback="window.our_Layers" %}
```

my view in django

```
def Usermap(request):
    plots1 = request.user.person.Persona.all()

    for Registration in plots1:
        LR=(Registration.parcels.lr)            
    context = {'plots':plots1,'LR':LR}
    return render(request, 'Cadastre/Usermap.html', context)
```

Have used that for loop in django to show me available lr which are 3 but i cant use django for loop tags inside the leaflet function any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to go around it..first i perform a for loop in django views and append my result in a list.
example

```
def Usermap(request):
    plots1 = request.user.person.Persona.all()
    LR =[]

    for Registration in plots1:
        LR.append(Registration.parcels.lr)            
    context = {'plots':plots1,'LR':LR}
    return render(request, 'Cadastre/Usermap.html', context)
```

then do another loop in html to access the list items and use it to style my map dynamically.
example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
datasets = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'Plots' %}",{
 style: function colors(feature){
     var LRS = {{LR|safe}};
     var x;
     for (x of LRS){                    
         switch(feature.properties.lr){                        
            case x:
                 return{
                    color: 'red'
                 };
            break
         }
      }                        
 },
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
</script>
```

I hope this help someone with same issue since there is no other answer thank you.